# Undefined is not defined in IE7

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer-7, undefined, history.js

I am using a JavaScript library (History.js) where the code is wrapped around this anonymous function:

```
 (function(window,undefined){
     //...
 })(window);
```

It works well in all browsers until I switch to IE7 compatibility mode. I drilled down to this "undefined" variable which is causing a script not being functional. In other words, IE7 seems to stop the script when it sees this undefined keyword.

I understand that this variable is used to create an undefined object but since it is really not defined anywhere, IE7 and possibly earlier do not work.

What's the workaround? has anybody come across the same issue?

Comment: That anon function is not getting invoked. Are you sure you copy/pasta'd it correctly?

Comment: Can you give us a minimal repro?  I just tried "javascript:1+undefined" and "javascript:alert(undefined)" in my IE 7 install, and both behaved as expected.

Comment: sorry - I just updated the code. I typed wrong.

Answer (score 0):

the snippet above does not actually execute the function. is this a copy/paste error? or is this your exact code? if so, try this:

```
(function(window, undefined) {
    //...
})(this);
```

note the final parentheses and the `this` object being passed (which maps back to the local var `window` inside the function.

hope that helps! cheers.

Comment: Thanks. My issue actually may be related to how history.js is using this undefined. Still looking into it

Answer (score 0):

The explanation and fix for this is here:

https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/issues/157

You just need to include json2.js before your code (https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)